# What is the best practice to customize existing Backstage's plugin?

Tags: backstage

I'm adding a button to an existing plugin in Backstage (@backstage/plugin-github-actions) (see the `view` button in my screenshot).

My plan was to keep the change as clean-n-small as possible. So, to show the custmized frontend view, I added my own EntityLayoutContent that reuses some object and functions from the original plugin. But it seems that every time I want to modify an object/function, then I have to copy many other files to satisfy the dependencies on `import ...` statement.

It ends up to be much easier for me to copy the entire plugin's code base to my Backstage app repository and act like it's my own plugin. But this way introduces a nightmare to keep the plugin up to date.

What is the best practice to cusomize an Backstage's plugin view?

[image]

I tried to "inherit" the frontend plugin's rendering object, does not work as missing internal const objects.

I copied the entire plugin code into my Backstage app, it works but don't know how to keep the plugin update later.